# Filter courses according to there category using angular material checkbox

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have two array called **1.Courses and 2.Categories** each courses have different category i want to filter the **courses** by **category** using mat-checkbox.

**example:** **javascript** is a course name and **scripting** is **category** .

Here is the **[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-fk9qph?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.ts)** 
and below is the screen shot of the approach:

[image]

It should work on multiple checkbox filtering Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the simplest way to do this with your current approach, IMO, would be to create a new course array `filteredCourses` and iterate that in your template.

`OnInit`, set `filteredCourses` to `courses` so it renders them all on init.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredCourses = this.courses;
 }
```

Next, you need some way of maintaining a list of the selected categories. This would be much easier if you used Angulars built in forms, but, in the absence of that, may I suggest the following:

`onSelect` (click), add the clicked category to a list of selected categories (on click, if it's not there, add it, else, remove it)

```
onSelect(selectedCategory: any) {
   this.selectCategory(selectedCategory);  
}

selectCategory(selectedCategory: any) {
   const index: number = this.selectedCategories.findIndex((cat: any) => { 
     return cat.id === selectedCategory.id 
   });

   if ( index === -1) {
      this.selectedCategories.push(selectedCategory);
   } else {
      this.selectedCategories.splice(index, 1);
   }
}
```

The next step would then to be to filter your `courses` array to only those where the the `categoryId` is included in the list of `selectedCategories` and set your `filteredCourses` array with the result, allowing the template to update. So, your `onSelect` function becomes:

```
onSelect(selectedCategory: any) {
   this.selectCategory(selectedCategory);
   this.filteredCourses = this.courses.filter((course: any) => {
     return this.selectedCategories.findIndex((cat: any) => {
        return course.categoryId === cat.id;
     }) !== -1;
   });
 }
```

Updated blitz with suggestion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-kq6xgd